# Convert nested/complex JSON to CSV not get actual output

Tags: c#, json, csv

Input json is (The json is little part of real data, real json is very long and more hierarchy. json line more than 30k)

```
  {
  "data": {
    "getUsers": [
      {
        "userProfileDetail": {
          "userStatus": {
            "name": "Expired"
          },
          "userStatusDate": "2017-04-04T07:48:25+00:00",
          "lastAttestationDate": "2019-02-01T03:50:42.6049634-05:00"
        },
        "userInformation": {
          "Id": 13610875,
          "lastName": "************",
          "suffix": null,
          "gender": "FEMALE",
          "birthDate": "1970-01-01T00:01:00+00:00",
          "ssn": "000000000",
          "ethnicity": "INVALID_REFERENCE_VALUE",
          "languagesSpoken": null,
          "personalEmail": null,
          "otherNames": null,
          "userType": {
            "name": "APN"
          },
          "primaryuserState": "CO",
          "otheruserState": [
            "CO"
          ],
          "practiceSetting": "INPATIENT_ONLY",
          "primaryEmail": "*****@*****.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "userProfileDetail": {
          "userStatus": {
            "name": "Expired newwwwwwwwwwww"
          },
          "userStatusDate": "2017-04-04T07:48:25+00:00",
          "lastAttestationDate": "2019-02-01T03:50:42.6049634-05:00"
        },
        "userInformation": {
          "Id": 13610875,
          "lastName": "************",
          "suffix": null,
          "gender": "FEMALE",
          "birthDate": "1970-01-01T00:01:00+00:00",
          "ssn": "000000000",
          "ethnicity": "INVALID_REFERENCE_VALUE",
          "languagesSpoken": null,
          "personalEmail": null,
          "otherNames": null,
          "userType": {
            "name": "APN"
          },
          "primaryuserState": "CO",
          "otheruserState": [
            "CO"
          ],
          "practiceSetting": "INPATIENT_ONLY",
          "primaryEmail": "*****@*****.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the code is

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
            // Collect column titles: all property names whose values are of type JValue, distinct, in order of encountering them.
            var jsonValues = obj.DescendantsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().Where(p => p.Value is JValue).GroupBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
            var jsonKey = jsonValues.Select(g => g.Key).ToArray();

            // Filter JObjects that have child objects that have values.
            var parentsWithChildren = jsonValues.SelectMany(g => g).SelectMany(v => v.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Skip(1)).ToHashSet();

            // Collect all data rows: for every object, go through the column titles and get the value of that property in the closest ancestor or self that has a value of that name.
            var rows = obj
                .DescendantsAndSelf()
                .OfType<JObject>()
                .Where(o => o.PropertyValues().OfType<JValue>().Any() && (o == obj || !parentsWithChildren.Contains(o))) // Show a row for the root object + objects that have no children.
                .Select(o => jsonKey.Select(c => o.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JObject>().Select(parent => parent[c])
                    .Where(v => v is JValue).Select(v => (string)v).FirstOrDefault()).Reverse() // Trim trailing nulls
                    .SkipWhile(s => s == null).Reverse());

            // Convert to CSV
            var csvRows = new[] { jsonKey }.Concat(rows).Select(r => string.Join(",", r));
            var csv = string.Join("\n", csvRows);
            Console.WriteLine(csv);
```

Here is the output i get:

> getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatus_name,getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatusDate,getUsers_userProfileDetail_lastAttestationDate,getUsers_userInformation_Id,getUsers_userInformation_lastName,getUsers_userInformation_suffix,getUsers_userInformation_gender,getUsers_userInformation_birthDate,getUsers_userInformation_ssn,getUsers_userInformation_ethnicity,getUsers_userInformation_languagesSpoken,getUsers_userInformation_personalEmail,getUsers_userInformation_otherNames,getUsers_userInformation_userType_name,getUsers_userInformation_primaryuserState,getUsers_userInformation_otheruserState,getUsers_userInformation_practiceSetting,getUsers_userInformation_primaryEmail
>   Expired,04/04/2017 13:18:25,02/01/2019 14:20:42
>   APN,,,13610875,************,,FEMALE,01/01/1970 05:31:00,000000000,INVALID_REFERENCE_VALUE,,,,CO,INPATIENT_ONLY,*****@*****.com

here userType > name not column is not in correct place and otheruserState array not come in output.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Maybe there is some LINQ kung-fu that could dig into those nested items to get your results but wouldn't it be easier to deserialize the json to a strong Type and code a converter to csv ?

Comment: create a class-based on this JSON and convert the JSON to class and use its properties

Comment: Do you need a comma after the curly brace, but before the closing square bracket for getUsers ? Not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Following process is what I would recommend since it does not skip the null values and doesnt throw errors if there are nulls. Process below creates a csv formatted string for each of the user in the json and writes down a string.empty for any null value.

List of strings are converted to | delimited since its going in a comma delimited format. **You should** update all the classes and use Capital first letter in attribute names. I am simply pasting what I got from json2csharp site.

**Get Classes for Json**

I used [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/#) site to convert your json to classes. Once i got the classes, i used an override method on `GetUser` to convert the user data to string.... then used that information to print it.

**Classes for the Json**

```
    public class UserStatus
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserProfileDetail
    {
        public UserStatus userStatus { get; set; }
        public DateTime userStatusDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastAttestationDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserType
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserInformation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string suffix { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime birthDate { get; set; }
        public string ssn { get; set; }
        public string ethnicity { get; set; }
        public List<string> languagesSpoken { get; set; }
        public string personalEmail { get; set; }
        public List<string> otherNames { get; set; }
        public UserType userType { get; set; }
        public string primaryuserState { get; set; }
        public List<string> otheruserState { get; set; }
        public string practiceSetting { get; set; }
        public string primaryEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetUser
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            List<string> userData = new List<string>
            {
                userProfileDetail.userStatus.name,
                userProfileDetail.userStatusDate.ToString(),
                userProfileDetail.lastAttestationDate.ToString(),
                userInformation.Id.ToString(),
                userInformation.lastName,
                userInformation.suffix?? string.Empty ,
                userInformation.gender?? string.Empty ,
                userInformation.birthDate.ToString(),
                userInformation.ssn?? string.Empty ,
                userInformation.ethnicity?? string.Empty ,
                string.Join("|", userInformation.languagesSpoken?? new List<string>()),
                userInformation.personalEmail?? string.Empty ,
                string.Join("|", userInformation.otherNames?? new List<string>() ),
                userInformation.userType.name?? string.Empty ,
                userInformation.primaryuserState?? string.Empty ,
                string.Join("|", userInformation.otheruserState),
                userInformation.practiceSetting?? string.Empty ,
                userInformation.primaryEmail
            };

            return string.Join(",", userData);
        }
        public UserProfileDetail userProfileDetail { get; set; }
        public UserInformation userInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public List<GetUser> getUsers { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
            public string GetHeader()
            {
                return "getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatus_name,getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatusDate,getUsers_userProfileDetail_lastAttestationDate,getUsers_userInformation_Id,getUsers_userInformation_lastName,getUsers_userInformation_suffix,getUsers_userInformation_gender,getUsers_userInformation_birthDate,getUsers_userInformation_ssn,getUsers_userInformation_ethnicity,getUsers_userInformation_languagesSpoken,getUsers_userInformation_personalEmail,getUsers_userInformation_otherNames,getUsers_userInformation_userType_name,getUsers_userInformation_primaryuserState,getUsers_userInformation_otheruserState,getUsers_userInformation_practiceSetting,getUsers_userInformation_primaryEmail";
            }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

**How to use the classes above**

```
    string json = File.ReadAllLines("locationOfJson");
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(rootObject.GetHeader()); // Prints Header
    foreach (var user in rootObject.data.getUsers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(user.ToString()); // Print Each User.
    }
```

**Output**

```
getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatus_name,getUsers_userProfileDetail_userStatusDate,getUsers_userProfileDetail_lastAttestationDate,getUsers_userInformation_Id,getUsers_userInformation_lastName,getUsers_userInformation_suffix,getUsers_userInformation_gender,getUsers_userInformation_birthDate,getUsers_userInformation_ssn,getUsers_userInformation_ethnicity,getUsers_userInformation_languagesSpoken,getUsers_userInformation_personalEmail,getUsers_userInformation_otherNames,getUsers_userInformation_userType_name,getUsers_userInformation_primaryuserState,getUsers_userInformation_otheruserState,getUsers_userInformation_practiceSetting,getUsers_userInformation_primaryEmail
Expired,4/4/2017 3:48:25 AM,2/1/2019 3:50:42 AM,13610875,************,,FEMALE,12/31/1969 7:01:00 PM,000000000,INVALID_REFERENCE_VALUE,,,,APN,CO,CO,INPATIENT_ONLY,*****@*****.com
```

I suggest copy pasting the data in excel to see how it fits. I tested it and seems like all the data goes correctly under their heading.

Comment: The above  json is little part of real data, real json is very long and more hierarchy. json line more than 30k.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the case you provided is below. It is using [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm) instead of LINQ to JSON to give you full control over output formatting. For example you did not specify how it should behave for arrays of string (*otheruserState*) so in my solution I separated string values with the dash. I'm using empty strings for null values.

```
string propertyName = "";
var isArray = false;
var arrayHeaderprinted = false;

var headers = new List<string>();
var data = new List<string>();
var arrayData = new List<string>();

using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                propertyName = (string)reader.Value;
                break;
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                isArray = true;
                break;
            case JsonToken.EndArray:
            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                isArray = false;
                if (arrayHeaderprinted)
                {
                    arrayHeaderprinted = false;
                    data.Add(string.Join("-", arrayData));
                }
                break;
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.Integer:
                if (isArray)
                {
                    if (!arrayHeaderprinted)
                    {
                        arrayHeaderprinted = true;
                        headers.Add(propertyName);
                    }
                    arrayData.Add(reader.Value.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    headers.Add(propertyName);
                    data.Add(reader.Value?.ToString() ?? "");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headers));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data));
```

The output it produces:

```
name,userStatusDate,lastAttestationDate,Id,lastName,suffix,gender,birthDate,ssn,ethnicity,languagesSpoken,personalEmail,otherNames,name,primaryuserState,otheruserState,practiceSetting,primaryEmail
Expired,04.04.2017 09:48:25,01.02.2019 09:50:42,13610875,************,,FEMALE,01.01.1970 01:01:00,000000000,INVALID_REFERENCE_VALUE,,,,APN,CO,CO-PP,INPATIENT_ONLY,*****@*****.com
```