# JSON to CSV conversion using ChoETL Some array value missing

Tags: c#, json, choetl

I am converting a JSON file to a CSV file. The JSON has multiple nested objects and large size. While converting, I am able to get all the values out of the JSON and into the CSV. However, array values are missing . I am using CHOETL library.
the sample json is (original json is long and big size)

```
{
    "getUsers": [
        {
            "UserInformation": {
                "Id": 1111122,
                "firstName": "*****1",
                "UserType": {
                    "name": "CP"
                },
                "primaryState": "MA",
                "otherState": [
                    "MA",
                    "BA"
                ],
                "createdAt": null
            }
        },
        {
            "UserInformation": {
                "Id": 3333,
                "firstName": "*****3",
                "UserType": {
                    "name": "CPP"
                },
                "primaryState": "MPA",
                "otherState": [
                    "KL",
                    "TN",
                    "DL",
                    "AP",
                    "RJ"
                ],
                "createdAt": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the `otherState` array in first array is two but second array its four. its not showing is csv.
the input json is long and nested hierarchy and mostly dynamic
the code is

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

            using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(msg)
                .WithFirstLineHeader()
                )
            {
                using (var r = new ChoJSONReader(@"E:/Temp/CSV/input/Data_Sample2.json")
                    .WithJSONPath("$..getUsers[*]")
                    )
                {
                    w.Write(r);
                }
            }
            File
```

the output is

```
UserInformation_Id,UserInformation_firstName,UserInformation_UserType_name,UserInformation_primaryState,UserInformation_otherState_0,UserInformation_otherState_1,UserInformation_createdAt
1111122,*****1,CP,MA,MA,BA, 3333,*****3,CPP,MPA,KL,TN,
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert nested/complex JSON to CSV not get actual output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59519370/convert-nested-complex-json-to-csv-not-get-actual-output)

Comment: Isnt this like the third time you are asking this same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to mention the CSV driver to scan and discover fields automatically using `MaxScanRows` property (default 1)

Sample code below shows how to

```
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();

using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
    .WithJSONPath("$..getUsers[*]")
    )
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(csv)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        .Configure(c => c.MaxScanRows = 2)
        .Configure(c => c.ThrowAndStopOnMissingField = false)
        )
    {
        w.Write(r);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString());
```

Comment: You saved lot of time, thanks @cinchoo

Answer (score 0):

I created a file test.json and put it in the bin directory. Test.json had the same contents above. then I used the following code:

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("test.json"))
{
   using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv").WithFirstLineHeader())
   {
      w.Write(r);
   }
}
```

It generated the file sample.csv with the right array values. Are you sure, stringbuilder msg has the right content.

Comment: its get output but i have two user, i want each user in single row. as per ur code its show only in single row. my real data have large size it difficult in single row